# Espresso IdlingResource polling frequency

Tags: android, android-espresso

I noticed that `Espresso` polls a particular `IdlingResource`'s `isIdleNow()` method every five second.

Is it possible to adjust this granularity?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Short answer:

No, it's baked into the `IdlingPolicies.dynamicIdlingResourceWarningPolicy` and not controlled by external configuration as of version 3.0.1. This policy controls the frequency of warning events that are posted to the handler. These events, in turn, cause the call to `isIdleNow()`

Slightly longer answer:

It is like this for a very good reason. `isIdleNow()` is not a place to set your application state. At the time `isIdleNow()` is called the state should already be known. The state should be updated with the call to `ResourceCallback::onTransitionToIdle` and generally(99% of a time) not inside of `isIdleNow()`

The documentation hints at it when it says that you should return immediately, but does not make it clear.

Updating the state in `isIdleNow()` makes it no better than just sleeping the thread conditionally. Actually, makes it even worse, as your tests are now 5 seconds slower on a per test basis. Which defeats the purpose of espresso as it kills the determinism of the test. And in my opinion determinism of espresso tests is what makes it so great thanks to the built-in main thread synchronization and idling resource interface.

With that being said there should not be a need to modify this timeout. Calling `ResourceCallback::onTransitionToIdle` will post this event to the handler and espresso will proceed immediately.

Unfortunately, there are lots of examples and even blogs that promote inefficient implementations.

These examples should be great sources of inspiration if you want a more conventional idling resource:

[okhttp idling resource](https://github.com/JakeWharton/okhttp-idling-resource/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/espresso/OkHttp3IdlingResource.java)

`DrawerActions$IdlingDrawerListener` bundled with espresso-contrib. [here is the source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/f69eb9ac2856f470cb79f57141f711ed3ceed99d/espresso/espresso-contrib/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/contrib/DrawerActions.java#203https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/f69eb9ac2856f470cb79f57141f711ed3ceed99d/espresso/espresso-contrib/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/contrib/DrawerActions.java#203).

`CountingTaskExecutorRule` from Room library, here is the [usage](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/androidTest/java/com/android/example/github/util/TaskExecutorWithIdlingResourceRule.java) of it.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the quick and detailed response. Let me read it and I'll respond after. Thanks again!

Comment: Hey Vlad!! Yes you're right, this behaviour is hard-coded in Espresso, and the only way to change it is to change the source and re-compile the jar. I ended up executing a `ViewAssertion` at some interval to check visibility (or some arbitrary other `View` state) before proceeding with the test. This works really well, but still sometimes Espresso waits too long before checking the `ViewAssertion` due to background tasks still not idle (I don't have much choice here since the team wants to keep production code free from test code at all costs... I know, right!?).

Comment: This is really bad. Want to use `IdlingResource` but can't now since the changes in my production code has change calling frequency for `isIdleNow()`, and now that's something i can't change. I've wasted a whole day debugging this.